# Multiple query execution as formula derivative

Tags: sql, postgresql

**FIRST QUERY**

```
WITH bar AS (
       SELECT wavelength, reflectance 
       FROM
         (SELECT 
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY NULL) As RowNumber, * 
          FROM deodar) As foo 
       WHERE (RowNumber % 5 = 0)
     )
    SELECT
       wavelength, 
       (LEAD(wavelength) OVER (ORDER BY wavelength) - wavelength) /
         (CASE WHEN (LEAD(reflectance) OVER (ORDER BY wavelength) - reflectance) = 0 THEN 1
               ELSE (LEAD(reflectance) OVER (ORDER BY wavelength) - reflectance) END)
          AS reflectance   
    FROM bar
```

This query output as input for the next operation, Once again this formula executes from the input of the above query in order to show result.

**SECOND QUERY**

```
 SELECT
          wavelength, 
          (LEAD(wavelength) OVER (ORDER BY wavelength) - wavelength) /
            (CASE WHEN (LEAD(reflectance) OVER (ORDER BY wavelength) - reflectance) = 0 THEN 1
                  ELSE (LEAD(reflectance) OVER (ORDER BY wavelength) - reflectance) END)
             AS reflectance
```

After the first query execution it will take its output as input for second query and perform the operation once again..

**QUERY TRIED**

```
SELECT 
   wavelength, 
   (LEAD(wavelength) OVER (ORDER BY wavelength) - wavelength) /
     (CASE WHEN (LEAD(reflectance) OVER (ORDER BY wavelength) - reflectance) = 0 THEN 1
           ELSE (LEAD(reflectance) OVER (ORDER BY wavelength) - reflectance) END)
      AS reflectance 
FROM (SELECT 
   wavelength, 
   (LEAD(wavelength) OVER (ORDER BY wavelength) - wavelength) /
     (CASE WHEN (LEAD(reflectance) OVER (ORDER BY wavelength) - reflectance) = 0 THEN 1
           ELSE (LEAD(reflectance) OVER (ORDER BY wavelength) - reflectance) END)
      AS reflectance   
FROM (
   SELECT wavelength, reflectance 
   FROM
     (SELECT 
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY NULL) As RowNumber, * 
      FROM deodar) As foo 
   WHERE (RowNumber % 5 = 0)
) )bar
```

This Query gives error...

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: And what's not working, do you get any error message ?

Comment: Your "second query" looks 100% identical to the query in the first example. So what exactly do you want to do with that query?

Comment: @OP, what do you mean by "gives error" ? Which error ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

```
SELECT 
   wavelength, 
   (LEAD(wavelength) OVER (ORDER BY wavelength) - wavelength) /
     (CASE WHEN (LEAD(reflectance) OVER (ORDER BY wavelength) - reflectance) = 0 THEN 1
           ELSE (LEAD(reflectance) OVER (ORDER BY wavelength) - reflectance) END)
      AS reflectance 
FROM (SELECT 
   wavelength, 
   (LEAD(wavelength) OVER (ORDER BY wavelength) - wavelength) /
     (CASE WHEN (LEAD(reflectance) OVER (ORDER BY wavelength) - reflectance) = 0 THEN 1
           ELSE (LEAD(reflectance) OVER (ORDER BY wavelength) - reflectance) END)
      AS reflectance   
FROM (
   SELECT wavelength, reflectance 
   FROM
     (SELECT 
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY NULL) As RowNumber, * 
      FROM deodar) As foo 
   WHERE (RowNumber % 5 = 0)
)results )bar --alias added here
```

When selecting from a subquery, the subquery must have an alias (= a name): typical syntax is `SELECT foo FROM (subquery) name` (emphasis on name). You can put `AS name` instead of `name`, but it's not mandatory.

Having an editor with parenthesis matching is very useful in this case.

Comment: Okay, can you test it now ?